# R Estou a tentar preencher uma tabela atraves de um ciclo loop, mas esta a demorar demasiado tempo. Como posso melhorar o desempenho do loop?

Tags: r, for

as colunas e os valores da tabela vao sendo preenchidos à medida que o ciclo corre.
Resumidamente, tenho uma tabela com dados de clientes (BD) e outra tabela com valores esperados futuros por idade (ESP). e o que o ciclo faz é, para um cliente com idade x, ir buscar todos os valores esperados para a idade atual e idade futura que estao noutra tabela. Em excel podia fazer isto rapidamente. Como melhorar o desempenho do ciclo em R?

A tabela ESP e a tabela BD:

```
ESP
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   IDADE    ESP
   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     0 100000
 2     1  99129
 3     2  99057
 4     3  99010
 5     4  98977
 6     5  98948
 7     6  98921
 8     7  98897
 9     8  98876
10     9  98855

BD
   IDADE_ACT
1         84
2         44
3         24
4         23
5         23
6         22
7         25
8         22
9         22
10        22
```

o CODIGO R que estou a usar

```
FUN <- function (BD, ESP) {
  anos<-ncol(ESP)
  n <- nrow(BD)
  DF <-  data.frame()
  for (i in 1:n) {
    idade <- BD[i, ]$IDADE_ACT
    if (is.na(idade)) {DF[i, ] <- 0}
    else {
      j <- 1
      while (j <= anos + 1) {
        if (idade >= 0 && idade + j <= nrow(ESP)) {
          DF[i, j] <- ESP[idade + j, 2]
        } else{(DF[i, j] <- 0)}
        j <- j + 1
      }
    } 
  }
  colnames(DF) <- c(0:anos)
  return(DF)
}
```

[image: imagem]

Comment: 1) Não sabemos o que são `ESP` e `BD`. Pode editar a pergunta com a saída de `dput(head(ESP, 20))` e o mesmo para `BD`, por favor? 2) Com `return` no fim isso é uma função; falta o início, o código está incompleto. Come é que a função é chamada?

Comment: obrigado pelo alerta. postei o cod errado e pus um ex das tabelas, mas basicamente, queria fazer algo muito semelhante ao vlookup em excel.